# Allowed characters in map key identifier in YAML?

Tags: validation, yaml

Which characters are and are not allowed in a key (i.e. `example` in `example: "Value"`) in YAML?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Any character (if properly quoted by either single quotes 'example' or double quotes "example"). Please be aware that the key does not have to be a scalar ('example'). It can be a list or a map.

Comment: does it mean it includes numbers?

Comment: @jpganz18, yes, and they don't even need to be quoted or escaped. Try it at http://www.yamllint.com/.

Comment: good [source](https://www.yaml.info/learn/quote.html) to understand what needs to be quoted

Answer (score 55):

According to the YAML 1.2 specification simply advises using printable characters with explicit control characters being excluded ([see here](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html)):

In constructing key names, characters the YAML spec. uses to denote syntax or special meaning need to be avoided (e.g. `#` denotes comment, `>` denotes folding, `-` denotes list, etc.).

Essentially, you are left to the relative coding conventions (restrictions) by whatever code (parser/tool implementation) that needs to consume your YAML document.  The more you stick with alphanumerics the better; it has simply been our experience that the underscore has worked with most tooling we have encountered.

It has been a shared practice with others we work with to convert the period character `.` to an underscore character `_` when mapping namespace syntax that uses periods to YAML. Some people have similarly used hyphens successfully, but we have seen it misconstrued in some implementations.