# Spaces in YAML keys

Tags: yaml

Is there a correct way to use spaces in YAML keys? Like

```
a test: "hello world!"
```

or

```
"a test": "hello world!"
```

or is it just a bad idea and one should use

```
a_test: "hello world!"
```

All of them seem valid in a yaml-Linter, but I didn't find any examples online using spaces in a key.

Comment: Related: [Allowed characters in Map key identifier YAML](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9065136/1983854). Interestingly, I just ran a test on Python and it appears to remove the spaces from the key name.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Allowed characters in map key identifier in YAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065136/allowed-characters-in-map-key-identifier-in-yaml)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

One thing is what is allowed, another is what is human readable.

Spaces are allowed in keys according to the specification and for those you don't need quotes (double or single, each with their own use). It is just a scalar string containing a space.

As for human readability, I tend to think of `a` and `test` in `a test` as not belonging together. That is of course caused by what I am used to, and that e.g. variables in most programming languages cannot have spaces (although my one of my first languages, Algol 68, did allow that). For human readability I would suggest using `a_test` over `"a test"` (or `'a test'`), but others might have different preferences.